# Deleting entity in async method in a loop

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I delete user activitiy entities using hibernate, but got this error:
*Error for user activity 461
org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: No class com.db.model.UserActivity entity with id 461 exists!*
I call this async method from scheduler. I know that EmptyResultDataAccessException is thrown if deleteById does not return entity. But I don't know why does it try to delete an entity that doesn't exists.
Explain me please.

```
@Async
@Override
@Transactional
public void deleteUserActivities(@NonNull LocalDateTime createdBefore) {
    for (Long uaId : userActivityRepository.findCreatedBefore(createdBefore)) {
        try {
            userActivityRepository.deleteById(uaId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error for user activity {}", uaId, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why this contraption? Why not just 1 single delete instead of findAll then delete one by one? This will degrade pretty quickly (performance wise) when your data starts to grow. The error will be thrown if there are 2 processes deleting (it is scheduled after all) where 1 has already removed the data (not yet committed) then the next one starts, gets the id (meanwhile thread 1 commits and thus deletes the data), thread 2 will now try to delete the same record(s) again as it has seen them before the commit of thread 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this method is called simulteneously in two threads, then both runs can get the same set of IDs. And through the for loop they are trying to delete the same entity, if first thread does it first, then the second fails.

This may happen when scheduler calls this method before the previous call ends

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't know why does it try to delete an entity that doesn't
> exists. Explain me please.

This issue is already fixed in [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2719) after 3.0.2 release. It will not throw exception now if there are no entity to be deleted.